# Reliable way to detect a JSONP request on the server side?

Tags: ajax, web, jsonp

I have a web application that can serve some requests to the same URL either as HTML or as JSON. So far I relied on the `Accept` HTTP header to determine what to return. Now there is a new requirement to be able to serve the JSON as a JSONP response if a specific URL parameter exists. Unfortunately most browsers request the `src` attribute of a `<script>` tag with an `Accept` header of `*/*`.

At the moment i see two options around this and both have some drawbacks:

1. When the `Accept` header is `*/*`, check for a `callback` parameter and if that parameter exists, serve JSONP. This might lead to the wrong content type when the `callback` parameter is used for different purposes.
2. Do not rely on the `Accept` header any more and use different URL paths for different content types. This might break backwards compatibility of applications that consume the JSON or lead to duplicate URLs.

Is there any other way to detect JSONP requests?

Comment: Typically an application will serve JSON-P (as `application/javascript` as per RFC4329) if `callback=` is included in the parameters. Treat it as a reserved word. Otherwise, the request is assumed to be JSON.

Comment: just saw this after years,I would presume when you make the request from a scrip tag, the browser would include "Content-type: application/javascript" header. So if you see this mime type (normally it would be nothing or text/plain) , even if there is no "callback" query parameter, it would be a safe bet that it is a JSONP call.